# table.remove in Lua script does not work

Tags: lua

I have problems with table.remove command in lua, it shows no error, but it just does not remove anything.

```
name = { "Patricia", "Linda", "Barbara", "Elizabeth", "Jennifer", "Maria"}
surname = { "McKechnie", "Musto", "Wheeler", "Bozeman", "Johnson", "Mason"}
usernames = { "Liall196466", "Therommover69", "Hinquallysx", "Wheinesxx", "Hationers77kt", "Andiedxxx"}
passwords = { "password", "password", "password", "password", "password", "password"}
for i=1,5,1
do
table.remove(name, 1)
table.remove(surname, 1)
table.remove(usernames, 1)
table.remove(passwords, 1)
end
```

Comment: I ran your code and it worked perfectly fine. Are you sure you don't have anything else modifying your arrays elsewhere?

Comment: After the loop, I see 4 tables each containing only one value; what are you expecting?

Comment: That is weird, it just does not do anything at my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not shown that in the table remains:

```
local function tprint(t)
    for k,v in pairs(t)  do print(k,v) end 
end
tprint(name)
tprint(surname)
tprint(usernames)
tprint(passwords)
```

my output:

```
1  Maria
1  Mason
1  Andiedxxx
1  password
```